# Open a specific View node with a link in an image

Tags: 7, navigation, views

I'm stumped. I'm not even sure how to ask the right questions to search out an answer.

What I have is a View of User Account images in a gallery. So far so good. I have another view of all User Account fields data presented as a node. So far so good there as well.

I want to click on the User Image in the gallery and go directly to that User's node in the other view.

The problem is not with attaching a URL to an image, but enabling sequential URLs to call the correct View node.

I feel like I'm missing some organizational overview understanding here. Maybe it's simple and I'm a doof.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather there are two possible approaches to this:

1. Either add a field for Link and then "Rewrite Results" to the content by referencing the node_id. Or do the rewrite on the image itself to the appropriate node_id. You might have to massage the urls for the other View or find a pattern to make this work.
2. Add a relationship to the gallery view to the Node that contains the UA fields. Add this relationship to the image field and then work it that way.

Hope this helps!